# ssh client times out to some servers, works on others

Tags: ssh, firewall, timeout

I have a strange problem and I'm not sure where to begin.  My ssh client works on some servers but times out on others.

Obviously, I checked that the servers are accessible via ssh from other locations.  From my machine A I can log on to C only by logging on to B first.  There are at least two servers for which this is the case.  To make matters more strange

1. `sudo ufw status` -> `Status: inactive`
2. `nmap -sT -p 22 <problem_server>` -> ...`22/tcp open  ssh`...

On one affected server I am getting: 
`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` and on the other I am getting `ssh: connect to host <problem_server> port 22: Connection timed out`

With both of these servers I can log in from other machines.  How can I troubleshoot such a problem?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that there might problems in the routes from your Machine to the servers. Are the other machines you tried out in the same subnet as yours?

Comment: Other machines from the same subnet can connect to the servers in question.

Comment: Can you try `ssh -vvvv …`? It might also be worth to have a look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Does the both configs have differences and if yes, what are they?